# MySQL Extract function gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, date

I'm running a query on an orders table to count total requests made by each user on any day during the month 6 months ago (e.g:- AUG 2013).

This works ok :-

```
SELECT userid,firstname,surname,sum(IF(MONTH(date_placed) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) and YEAR(date_placed) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)), 1,0))
FROM requests 
WHERE homelib='SBC'
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY surname;
```

But this fails with `SQL` syntax error :-

```
SELECT userid,firstname,surname,sum(IF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_placed) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)), 1,0))
FROM requests 
WHERE homelib='SBC'
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY surname;
```

Is there a more efficient SQL statement to do this? 
something like:

```
 YEAR_MONTH(date_placed) = YEAR_MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

It must only look at orders made on any day during the month 6 month ago (e.g:- during AUG 2013) and dynamically calculate 6 months ago from whenever the query is run.

Comment: The error is :-
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR_MONTH FROM date_placed ) = EXTRACT ( YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, EXTRACT does not work on date arithmetic. I am not sure about my approach but you can give it a try. Here is the query:

`SELECT 
userid,
firstname,
surname,
sum(IF(date_format(date_placed,"%y-%m") = date_format(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), "%y-%m"), 1,0))
FROM requests 
WHERE homelib='SBC'
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY surname;`

Comment: Thanks Neels, that seems to work well. There is something wierd going on because the following statement also gives the same syntax error :-
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2014-02-01'); How can that be?!

Comment: Welcome. EXTRACT is a rarely used function as far as I know. So don't bug yourself with it. :)